# resizing table based on child actors (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

I have a maintable (Table), which contains an innertable (Table), which contains a HorizontalGroup, which contains a Label with the Text "First words.".

Maintable
  InnerTable
    HorizontalGroup
      Label1

After this situation my width of the Maintable is 195

[image]

Then adding a new Label with the words "additional words". The maintable still remains with the size 195 and you can see my background is still the same size.

[image]

How can I achieve, that the main table is resized depending on the child hierarchie like mine is ?

Code:

```
package com.xxx.tests.dialogtest.tabletest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.NinePatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.HorizontalGroup;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.NinePatchDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.xxx.layouts.SkinManager;

public class TableTestMitInnerTable extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private Stage stage;
    private Table maintable;
    private Table innerTable;
    private HorizontalGroup horizontalGroup;
    private Skin skin;
    private int counter = 0;

    public void create() {

        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(SkinManager.getSkin()));

        maintable = new Table();
        maintable.setDebug(true);

        innerTable = new Table();
        //innerTable.setDebug(true);
        horizontalGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
        Label label = new Label("First words.", skin);

        horizontalGroup.addActor(label);
        innerTable.add(horizontalGroup);
//        horizontalGroup.setFillParent(true);
//        innerTable.setFillParent(true);

        maintable.add(innerTable).pad(20);
        stage.addActor(maintable);

        maintable.setPosition(300,300);
        maintable.setBounds(maintable.getX(), maintable.getY(), maintable.getPrefWidth(), maintable.getPrefHeight());
        maintable.setBackground(new NinePatchDrawable(getNinePatch(("skins/gacstyle/raw/window.9.png"))));

        System.out.println("Size before adding label : " + maintable.getWidth());

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    private NinePatch getNinePatch(String fname) {
        // Get the image
        final Texture t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fname));
        return new NinePatch( new TextureRegion(t, 1, 1 , t.getWidth() - 2, t.getHeight() - 2), 10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.6f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        counter++;
        if(counter == 1){
            horizontalGroup.addActor(new Label(" additional words ! ", skin));
            System.out.println("Size after adding label : " + maintable.getWidth());
        }
        super.render();
        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not fix the table's size by removing the `maintable.setBounds` call.

Comment: Problem is, when removing the bounds then the ninepatch has no size and I can't see any background ninepatch anymore.

Comment: You should take a look into the Button class, it does that what you want to achieve.

Comment: No I don't want to use a button. This is just a small example, that looks like a button. This can also be a big table with lots of entries, that I like to manage myself and like to have my own Ninepatches.

Comment: I did not suggest to use a button, I suggested you should take a look into the Button class to see how it is done there.